# Disable username validation on edit

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created my validation for unique username and now I can't edit my user. It's saying that username is already taken which makes sense since it's taken by the user that I'm trying to edit. I don't even want to edit username but because of this error I cannot edit any other field as well.

**How can I disable unique username validation for my EDIT action?**

Validator

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    if (value == null) return false;
    FinanceDataContext _db = new FinanceDataContext();
    var user = _db.Users.ToList().Where(x => x.Username.ToLower() == value.ToString().ToLower()).SingleOrDefault();
    if (user == null) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Action

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(User u)
{
    // Get user we want to edit
    var user = _db.Users.Where(x => x.ID == u.ID).SingleOrDefault();
    if (user == null) return HttpNotFound();

    // Set values and save changes
    user.Address = u.Address;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.Password)) user.Password = Infrastructure.Encryption.SHA256(u.Password);
    _db.SaveChanges(); // validation error

    return null;
}
```

Model

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [UniqueUsername(ErrorMessage = "Username is already taken")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Error

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See
>   'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Comment: can you show from where the method "IsValid" get called from "CheckUsername"? Show the code of this action result.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan It's used for client-side JS validation, I removed it to not confuse anyone else. `[UniqueUsername]` is what's causing problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by passing whole object to my validator and then checking id's as well as usernames.

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    var user = (User)value;
    if (user == null) return true;

    FinanceDataContext _db = new FinanceDataContext();
    var u = _db.Users.Where(x => x.Username.ToLower() == user.Username.ToLower() && x.ID != user.ID).SingleOrDefault();
    if (u == null) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the "ID" property in "AdditionalFields" parameter of UniqueUsername Attribute so I guess your code should be like this

**Class Property :**

```
[Required]
[UniqueUsername(ErrorMessage = "Username is already taken", AdditionalFields = "ID")]
public string Username { get; set; }
```

**Validate Action :**

```
public ActionResult UniqueUsername(string userName, int id)
{
    FinanceDataContext _db = new FinanceDataContext();
    var user = _db.Users.ToList().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username.ToLower() == value.ToString().ToLower() && x.ID != id);
    return Json(user == null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: No, `Remote` is used for client-side validation. It has nothing to do with server-side.

Comment: I seem to be close, however how can I pass ID? When I try `[UniqueUsername(ErrorMessage = "Username is already taken", id = ID)]` I get `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Finance.Models.User.ID.get`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626322/passing-data-from-the-model-into-custom-validation-class this helped me out

Answer (score 1):

Could you pass in the user id into the IsValid method and make sure the user returned doesn't have the same user id?

Comment: Yes, sure. But I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would like to contribute.

This code:

```
var user = _db.Users.ToList().Where(x => x.Username.ToLower() == value.ToString().ToLower()).SingleOrDefault();
```

Is not performatic, because when you do a `ToList()` you execute the whole query. In this case, what you are doing is retrieving ALL USERS from the database and them doing your filter in memory.

I would sugest you to do this:

```
_db.Users.Where(x => x.Username.ToLower() == value.ToString().ToLower()).SingleOrDefault();
```

Since you just want to retrieve one record, there is no need to call the `ToList()` method. Just the `SingleOrDefault()` at the end is enough.

Comment: You can't do `.ToLower()` since LINQ does not recognize it. So you need to convert it to list first.

Comment: Ahh, no. My bad. `.ToLower()` is recognized by LINQ and it works. Some function don't, however. Thanks for this.